# Recursion from main thread causes stuck text fields

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm using a recursive function to test if a text field is updated. When the function is called though, the text field freezes and can't be edited. Any suggestions?

```
           super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
                    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {

                        for item in 1...16 {
                            sleep(1)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                                testValue(textField: self.inputTextField, item: item)


                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
        func testValue(textField: UITextField, item: Int) {
            if textField.text == "Enter Data" {
                sleep(1)
                testValue(textField: textField, item: item)

            } else if self.inputTextField.text != "Enter Data" {
                let view = self.view.viewWithTag(item)
                if let btn = view as? UIButton {
                    btn.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
                        }
                    }
            }

        }
        
        }
```

Also confused because the else conditioned is evaluated at "not equal" even though the default text field value is "Enter Data". So this thing is pretty confusing to me, would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: The `sleep(1)` in `testValue(textField: UITextField, item: Int)` is been executed in the main thread... I'm curious as to the point of doing this, why not use a delegate to monitor the change of the text field?  Do you really care about doing real time validation?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. As far as I could tell everything here is being executed in the main thread. I get the same error when I remove ```sleep(1)```

Comment: `DispatchQueue.global` is working on a background thread, `DispatchQueue.main` brings you back to the main thread - this is all rather brute force and would better solved using an appropriate delegate

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the advice.